# How do I make a div stretch in a flexbox of dynamic height?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a stacked layout using flexbox.  Ideally it'd look like this:

[image: 2 boxes stacked vertically, the top is red and 4x the size of the bottom, which is blue]

where the bottom (blue) div is a fixed height of `250px` and the top div is `n-250`, where `n` is the size of the parent container--in another words, the top should stretch to fill the container.

I have some idea of how to do this when I have the container height, but I'd rather avoid having to determine that variable at runtime.

This issue has been covered at length in various forms , but none seem to address this simple use-case ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space), for example, works with a header/content/footer, but ostensibly not with just content/footer).

I've set up a [codepen with the example](http://codepen.io/brandonmp44/pen/xgbgPV).

Comment: Why is this anything more complicated than a `flex-grow` on the top div?

Comment: FYI in your codepen you have 2 errors in the HTML that prevent it working. </top> instead of </div> and bottom="bottom" instead of id="bottom"

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygygmy

Comment: If the height of the container isn't known or resolveable (e,g, a fixed value) then, in general, *you can't*. Note all of the current answers below require that the height of the container is known. If it isn't...they won't work AFAIK.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this is answering your question using the `flex-grow: 1;`. hope it helps

https://jsfiddle.net/BradChelly/ck72re3a/

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #444;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: stretch;
}
.box1 {
  width: 100%;
  background: steelblue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.box2 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: indianred;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know... still terrible, even Crayola got rid of "flesh" and "indian red"

Answer (score 3):

Minimum line of code. **Brad's** answer is correct. But here I used `flex` instead of `flex-grow` and removed `align-items`

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.top {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
}
.bottom {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jxrzcduv/)** here

Comment: What is the reason to use `flex` instead of `flex-grow`?

Comment: shorthand, like border instead of border-color

Answer (score 1):

That can be done without `flexbox` by simply using [CSS Calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  height: 100vh;
}
.top {
  background: lightblue;
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
.bottom {
  height: 100px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

If you want it to work on older browsers, update these rules like this

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
}
```